# Build gradle failed for google play services version

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

When I try to execute buid.gradle I get this error on android studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.
```

and this is the module build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gs.lasarenas"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

In this file the play services version is 8.4.0 but I don't know whre I have to update the version from 8.3.0 to 8.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

well try this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Adding `'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end solved it for me

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use jars

   - Remove this line `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
2. Do not use `play-services`.

   - Please choose one like: `play-services-analytics`

For example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Check my answer. See google play services here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```